# WPF setting a MenuItem.Icon in code

Tags: c#, wpf, icons, menuitem

I have an images folder with a png in it.  I would like to set a MenuItem's icon to that png.  How do I write this in procedural code?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
menutItem.Icon = new System.Windows.Controls.Image 
       { 
           Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/sample.png", UriKind.Relative)) 
       };
```

Comment: This helped us tremendously. We had to first create an Image, then assign the source of that Image to the BitMapImage, then set menuItem.Icon = Image object, but it worked.

Comment: I edited the answer so that new visitors to this question gets working code in case they miss this comment thread

Answer (score 23):

```
<MenuItem>
  <MenuItem.Icon>
    <Image>
      <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="/your_assembly;component/your_path_here/Image.png" />
      </Image.Source>
    </Image>
  </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Just make sure your image in also included in the project file and marked as resource, and you are good to go :)

Comment: Original question was for procedural code.  Also, I believe in XAML you could write `<Image Source="/CreditAlpha;component/Images/ColorWheel.png" />` inside the `<MenuItem.Icon>`

Comment: +1 for showing the right way... XAML way... to do it. @Neil, +1 to you and I edited to your suggestion, as that is the correct way to do it

Comment: Just because it is done in XAML does not necessarily make it the right way.

Answer (score 18):

Arcturus's answer is good because it means you have the image file in your project rather than an independent folder.

So, in code that becomes...

```
menutItem.Icon = new Image
        {
        Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/your_assembly;component/yourpath/Image.png"))
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit shorter :D

```
<MenuItem Header="Example">
   <MenuItem.Icon>
      <Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/Example.png"/>
   </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I used it (this way it dont need to be built into the assembly):

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
string imagePath = "D:\\Images\\Icon.png");
Image icon = new Image();
icon.Source= new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.Absolute));
item.Icon = icon;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me

```
<MenuItem Header="delete   ctrl-d" Click="cmiDelete_Click">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image>
            <Image.Source>
                <ImageSource>Resources/Images/delete.png</ImageSource>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using vb.net, to do this you need to use this:
`menuItem.Icon = New Image() With {.Source = New BitmapImage(New Uri("pack://application:,,,/your_assembly;component/yourpath/Image.png"))}`

Answer (score -5):

You can also use your Visual Studio to insert a icon. This is the easiest way

- Right click at you project in the solution explorer
- chose Properties
- Make sure you're in the application page.
- @ recources you see: Icon and Manifest
- @ Icon: Click browse and pick your icon.

Problem solved.

Comment: This works for WinForms. The question was how to set it manually from code.