# Unable to set System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.Icon thru a setter

Tags: wpf, xaml, icons, contextmenu, menuitem

Hi I am trying to have a [MenuItem.Icon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.icon.aspx) set thru a style setter:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItem_Delete" TargetType="MenuItem"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="_Delete"/>
    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="Resources/Delete.png"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I get the following exception at runtime:
Cannot add content of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' to an object of type 'System.Object'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' in markup file 'WpfApplication1;component/application.xaml' Line 164 Position 26.

In the other hand, this is the example in the above link:

```
<MenuItem Header="New">
  <MenuItem.Icon>
    <Image Source="data/cat.png"/>
  </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was desperatly searching the web for an answer and I think this is a WPF bug.

I reported it @ [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=497408), please vote and validate or share your ideas with Microsoft if you have some.

**Update**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239/wpf-setting-a-menuitem-icon-in-code) post helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same issue.
I found the same error on aonther thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/81a106dd-4d06-4506-820a-30fe96a39112.
According to their solution, you may try this one. But binding executes only for last element in MenuItem collection. It's so bad!

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItem_Delete" TargetType="MenuItem"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Image x:key="DeleteIcon" Source="Resources/Delete.png"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="_Delete"/>
    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{DynamicResource DeleteIcon}" />
</Style>
```

Is there any update? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The next code will solve this issue.

```
<Style x:Key="StyleNewContext" TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="ImageNewContext" Source="{StaticResource ImageSourceNewContext}" />
        <Image x:Key="ImageNewContextDisabled" Source="{StaticResource ImageSourceNewContextDisabled}" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{DynamicResource ImageNewContext}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{DynamicResource ImageNewContextDisabled}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Regards,
Peter