# ContextMenu in Style setter

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, styles

Does anyone know why this would produce an XamlParseException "Cannot add content of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu' to an object of type 'System.Object'":

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas ClipToBounds="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Remove" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the following works just fine?

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="NodeContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Remove" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas ClipToBounds="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource NodeContextMenu}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: that is weird. must be something to do with Value expecting an object but I dont see why that would cause an exception... If this is in Expression Blend it might be worth re-opening everything because it can play up sometimes

Comment: its in visual studio 2008 while the application is executed, i moved the context menu to resources and it works but i think it should work with the setter also, maybe its a bug

Comment: This is effectively the same issue as with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495489/unable-to-set-system-windows-controls-menuitem-icon-thru-a-setter).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug that has since been fixed - the code in question generates a XAML parse exception when targeting .NET 3.5, but works fine for me when targeting .NET 4.0. If you follow the link provided in the comments above, you will find a connect issue with comments from others indicating the problem has gone away with .NET 4.0.