# Add an Icon To WPF TreeView's ContextMenu Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have a WPF contextmenu and I want to add an Item with Icon to this in my C# code.
How Can I Do This???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were already questions like this. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239/wpf-setting-a-menuitem-icon-in-code).
So that you wouldn't have to drill down here:

```
menuItem.Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/sample.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: thanks.But What is The Namespace Of BitmapImage???Can I Use System.Drawing.Bitmap???

Comment: System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage in in PresentationCore.dll

Answer (score 1):

Should work for you.

```
<ContextMenu  x:Key="MyContextMenu" >
     <MenuItem  Header="Item1" Click="Ietm1_Click" 
           Icon="{StaticResource ItemIco}" />              

</ContextMenu>
```

and someone in resources reachable from this cose

```
<Image x:Key="ItemIco" Source="Images/ItemIco.png"/>
```

Where `Images`, natuarally, is a folder of realtive path, in this case.

Comment: No. I Have A DLL(Class Library) And I Don't Have Any Access To XAML Code.I Want to Do it In My C# Code