# How to get an icon from a picture and used it as a normal image in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone, icons

Here is a picture which contains lots of icons in MSDN: http://i3.msdn.microsoft.com/areas/epx/content/images/imagesprite.png. How can I get one of those icons and use that icon in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MS Paint, open image & crop all the icons and save it in separate folder.

Set background of every icon with transparent background color.

Now you can use all icons in your application.

Comment: That's right:), but is there a way to realize it in XAML?

Comment: For which control you want to use icon??.. Can you provide me your XAML code?? You can visit this link for MenuItem -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239/wpf-setting-a-menuitem-icon-in-code

Comment: I'd like to use it like this: `<Image Stretch="None" Source="/Assets/imagesprite.png">
                <Image.Clip>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="100,0,20,20"/>
                </Image.Clip>
            </Image>`

Comment: Mark this as the answer though I didn't get what I want. Of cause this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
<MenuItem.Icon>
       <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="pack://application:,,,/Image Clipping;component/Assets/imagesprite.png">
       </Image>
</MenuItem.Icon>
```

Comment: You might misunderstood what I want. I want to get various of single icons from that long picture, and then use the single icon as an image in other place. No matter as what. The key point is realize these in XAML. :)

Comment: Sorry. The key point is how to get the various single icons :)